# How to reference a favicon in a monorepo?

Tags: css, next.js, favicon

How can I add a rel link to a favicon inside a monorepo with nextjs? I'm not sure what constitutes the root file inside this structure.

The folder structure is this boilerplate [repo](https://github.com/NoQuarterTeam/boilerplate).

Inside the web repo, I made a public folder and added the favicon file, and then in the _document.tsx file, I added the following, which doesn't generate any errors, but it also doesn't update the favicon:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"></link>
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png"></link>
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"></link>
          <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest"></link>
```

I also tried adding:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

which is a file inside the public folder. It also doesn't populate the browser bar with the favicon.

When I inspect the page elements however, I can see the icon in the code inspector.

Is source relative to the _document.tsx, or the web folder itself? Or something else?

Comment: It's relative to the `public` folder that should be in the root of the Next.js app. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving.

Comment: Thank you. Something is definitely wrong then. I named the folder public (which is at the same level as the src folder, and removed assets from the link rels in the _document.tsx file but I still can't get it to generate. I'll add this to my list of problems to investigate tonight. Thanks for the reference to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `assets` folder inside the `public` folder and then your code should work.

Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called public in the root directory. Files inside public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/).

Related to the static files you can read [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) from the official page.

if you wanna use a layout component you can do this

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const Layout = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"></link>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/favicon-32x32.png"></link>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/favicon-16x16.png"></link>
      <link rel="manifest" href="/assets/site.webmanifest"></link>
    </Head>
    // Other layout/components
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out why this isnt updating the favicon tonight.